# Sequences (using as ID) issue in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using sequences to create IDs, so while executing insert stored procedure it will create unique value for ID. But after some time it is losing the definition for the sequence.

**Not sure why this is happening again and again and how to solve the problem?**

I am using Oracle SQL Developer and in the edit table property there is 'Identity Column' setting. See below:
[image]

Next step is setting up trigger and sequence:
[image]

It was working fine for some time until this property defaulted. Now it is not there anymore:
[image]

Still have this trigger and sequence object in the schema and able to setup again but it will break later.

**How to avoid this problem in future?**

Comment: Please show a [mcve] and details of the issue.

Comment: Most probably some code is inserting into that table _without_ using the sequence.

Comment: What does "re-link column property with existing sequence and trigger" mean exactly? What steps do you need to repeat?

Comment: added more comments

Comment: Is the trigger working anyway even if SQL Developer doesn't detect it? If so, it might be a problem with that specific GUI tool.

Comment: He seems to be describing the exact same issue I am experiencing...as follows: 1. Using Oracle SQL Developer, create a table and add an "Identity Column" of type "Column Sequence" 2. Use the "Edit Table" function in SQL Developer to make some random additional change or changes to the table (changes that should not change the 'Identity Column' created previously.) 3. Identity column mysteriously gets set back to default value of 'None'. 4. Insert query fails! This has been occurring to me for several years. Updated SQL Developer to latest version...issue still remains.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just a bug/limitation in your client software, Oracle SQL Developer. The "Identity Column" tab is a handy way to create the corresponding sequence and trigger but it doesn't seem to recognise existing elements. I've just verified my own system and that's exactly what happens.

It makes sense, because adding a new sequence and trigger is a pretty straightforward task (all you need is a template) but displaying current sequence is hard given that a trigger can implement any conceivable logic. Surely it could be done but the cost-benefit ratio probably left things this way.

In short, your app is not broken so nothing needs to be fixed on your side.

Answer (score 0):

**This is what I received from IT support regarding the issue:**

A few possibilities that might cause this:

1 - Another user with limited privileges might be editing the table using SQL Developer. In this case, if this user's privilege is not enough to obtain the sequence and/or trigger information from the database, the tool might leave the fields blank and disable it when table changes are saved.

2 - The objects are being changed or removed outside of SQL Developer, causing it to lose the information. In my tests I noticed that dropping the trigger and recreating it with the same name caused the identity property information to be lost on SQL Developer.

Even being the trigger enabled, and working for inserts it could not retrieve the information.

Then, if I run an alter trigger to enable it (even tough dba_trigger is reporting it as already enabled), SQL Developer will list the information again:
ALTER TRIGGER "AWS"."TABLE1_TRG" ENABLE;

So it looks like there are some issues with the SQL Developer, that is causing this behavior.
Next time it happen, please check if the trigger still exist on the database and is enabled with the query below:

```
select owner, trigger_name, TRIGGER_TYPE, TRIGGERING_EVENT, TABLE_OWNER, TABLE_NAME, STATUS
from dba_triggers
where trigger_name = 'ENTER_YOUR_TRG_NAME'; --Just change the trigger name in WHERE
```

Comment: Did you get this answer from Oracle support or support at your company? I can confidently say that through experiencing this issue many times over the last few years, it occurs when the table is edited in SQL Developer, but not every time it is edited. Somehow the Identity Column gets reset to the default value: None. Therefore, there is a bug in SQL Developer.